# Алгоритм отсечения "Fast Clipping"

Tags: c, графика, c++, алгоритм

Описание алгоритма можно прочитать например [тут](http://algolist.manual.ru/graphics/clip_seg.php).

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в этом алгоритме. Я никак не могу понять зачем вообще мне нужны эти коды? Препод сказал, что надо находить точки пересечения линий фигуры с окном отсечения через уравнение прямой, а вот зачем вообще эти коды нужны не ясно...

Найду я коды концов отрезка, ну преобразую их в код линии и что мне это дает?

Само отсечение  происходит либо путем закрашивания белым лишнего (по белому фону), либо вообще не рисовать ничего лишнего.

Код:

```
#define LineCode(start,end) (start << 4) | end
#define Intersection_x(x1, y1, x2, y2, y) {(x1*y2-x2*y1-y*(x1-x2))/(y2-y1),y}
#define Intersection_y(x1, y1, x2, y2, x) {x,(x1*y2-x2*y1-x*(y2-y1))/(x1-x2)}

unsigned char CODE(RECT clip, POINT point)
{
    unsigned char byte = 0;
    if (point.y < clip.top)
        byte |= 8;
    else
        if (point.y > clip.bottom)
            byte |= 4;
    if (point.x > clip.right)
        byte |= 2;
    else
        if (point.x < clip.left)
            byte |= 1;
    return byte;
}
```

В конечном счете мне нужно что-то типа:

```
bool ClipLine(HDC hdc, RECT clip, POINT start, POINT end);
```

Comment: Эти "коды" нужны только для того, чтобы не вычислять повторно условия выхода координат за пределы прямоугольного окна.

Comment: >Эти "коды" нужны только для того, чтобы не вычислять повторно >условия выхода координат за пределы прямоугольного окна.

но как мне их использовать? можете привести пример?

Comment: >но как мне их использовать? можете привести пример?

1. в `V_CSclip` это `ck` и `cn`: если `cn == 0` и `ck == 0`, то отрезок находится полностью внутри окна, т.е. он его не пересекает.
2. в `V_FCclip` свитч реагирует сразу на все варианты "склейки" из этих двух кодов: младший байт - код для конечной точки, старший байт - для начальной. (поэтому считается самым быстрым)  
 --  
имеется еще один магический трюк: если `(cn & ck) != 0`, то отрезок уже за пределами окна (обе точки расположены по одну сторону относительно окна), и расчитывать для него координаты пересечения с окном не требуется.

Comment: в общем уже не суть, разобрался сам